# Can't kill firefox process

Tags: linux, firefox, process

I have firefox that crashes every so often on my Ubuntu machine.
I can't seem to kill the process when this happens. The process' name is `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox`

I've tried:

```
pkill -f firefox
pkill -9 firefox
kill <id>
```

I tried killing it in `htop`. I saw there were 3 sub processes there. I could kill two of them but not the `plugin-container` process.

I ran `ps auxww` and the process does not show a `U` to indicate that it's stuck. It does show a `D` however.

Comment: Please show us the output of `ps aux | grep firefox`.

Comment: You may find an answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78689/fix-firefox-is-already-running-issue-in-linux --- Althoug for me what worked was shutting down the machine after doing that.

Answer (score -1):

type

```
ps aux | grep firefox
```

note the JOB ID type the following line

```
kill 4347
```

4347 is example the job id

i think it may help :)

Comment: He's already done that, he tried `kill`, `pkill` and `pkill -9` and none of them worked.